# Android image scaling and alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to show an image scaled while preserving its aspect ratio, but at the same time align it to the bottom.

Using android:scaleType="FitXY" causes the image to be centered vertically and horizontally, so it doesn't get aligned to the bottom.
Using "FitEnd" causes the image to be aligned to the bottom right corner, so it isn't centered horizontally.

Is there any way to get around this? Maybe using some matrix to scale it (scaleType="matrix")?

EDIT: To clarify a bit on what it is I want exactly...

I have an ImageView, whose layout (location, size, gravity, etc.) I can't change. I want to load a bitmap as its source image, but have that bitmap get scaled to the ImageView's size (preserving the aspect ratio of the bitmap) and then aligned to the ImageView's bottom.

EDIT: After trying everything I could think of (and everything that was suggested here), we ended up sub-classing ImageView and doing the scaling/translation ourselves in onDraw.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `android:scaleType="centerInside"` instead of `fitXY`.

---

Layout being used in a Blrfl Labs application to scale an image to fit the area the layout gives it without hosing up the aspect ratio:

```
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blah_blah_blah"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    />
```

Comment: centerInside won't scale the image, just center it

Comment: Not according to the documentation:  "Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding)."  I'm using it successfully in an application; actual layout added to answer above.

Comment: Seems like centerInside only scales down, not up. You might try fitCenter, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

if your `ImageView` is inside a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try adding:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

to your ImageView along with FitXY scaling.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the ImageView's size and location. What I want is for the image that is loaded to be scaled and then stuck to the bottom of the Image.

Comment: That's what layout_gravity does. It affects the gravity of the image within its container, it wont actually change the psotion of the container itself.

Comment: True, but all the layout_ properties are "inherited" from the layout the View is placed in. Specifically, this would work if the image is in a LinearLayout, but not if it's inside a RelativeLayout. However, now that I think about it, maybe I can just add a LinearLayout that wraps it - that'll probably solve it.